# How to create a custom loop ordered by Categories on a Page Template?

Tags: categories, get-posts, loop

Ex.

Category 1

Post 1

Post 2

Post 3

Post ....

Category 2

Post 1

Post 2

Post 3

Post ....

Category ....

Post 1

Post 2

Post 3

Post ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you're looking for nested loops. This will list the most recent 5 posts in every category on your site:

```
foreach ( get_terms('category') as $category ) {

    echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( get_posts( 'cat='.$category->term_id ) as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Add the name of the custom post type and any other variables you may want to modify the loop with to the call to `get_posts`. You can look through the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for a list of argument that can be passed.